# Cant deserialize object - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Tags: android, gson, json-deserialization

First let me say, I have searched before posting, just cant find the answer.

I'm having trouble de-serializing a JSON. It is a valid JSON (checked at http://jsonlint.com/)
and it was produced with servicestack json serializer.

I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

Here is my JSON sent by the server:

```
{
    "artistName": "",
    "pathInfo": "C:\\Users\\Unknown\\Desktop\\Audio Sketches\\Chill.mp3",
    "indexPos": 0,
    "messageType": "song"
}
```

How it being received:

```
{"artistName":"","pathInfo":"C:\\Users\\Unknown\\Desktop\\Audio Sketches\\Chill.mp3","indexPos":0,"messageType":"song"}
```

Here is the object to hold it:

```
public class Song {

    private String artistName;
    private String albumName;
    private String titleName;
    private String pathInfo;
    private String indexPos;
    private String messageType;


    public Song() {
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the JSON as you got it exactly not formatted and not modified at all

Comment: How are you parsing it, post the code please :)

Comment: I'm doing, Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
           Song song = gson.fromJson(type, Song.class);

Thanks for help

Comment: what is `type` here in your last comment. It's working fine for me. I passed JSON string where you are using `type`.

Comment: type is a string holding the JSON -{"artistName":"","pathInfo":"C:\\Users\\Unknown\\Desktop\\Audio Sketches\\Chill.mp3","indexPos":0,"messageType":"song"}

Comment: @Braj thank you!!!! I'm an idiot - type was not the string holding the JSON, it hold just a key from the JSON. I must have been working on it for too long. Post it as an answer and I will select it as the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I end up finding the answer myself but thanks to all that supported and helped.

This is the code that received the JSON object and initiate the Deserialization using GSON.

```
 Map messageObjMap = new Gson().fromJson(message, Map.class);
 String type = messageObjMap.get("messageType").toString();

 switch (type) {
     case "song":
         try {
             Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
             Song song = gson.fromJson(message, Song.class);
             ...
             ...
         } ...
     ...
 }
```

"message" was suppose to be the entire JSON. Instead it was a only a key parsed from the JSON and this is why the deserializtion didn't work. Hope that will help someone

Comment: Great work :), Thank you for the answer, now I learned Gson :)

Comment: Yes Gson is very cool and cleaner then parsing the elements yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = "{\"artistName\":\"\",\"pathInfo\":\"C:\\Users\\Unknown\\Desktop\\Audio Sketches\\Chill.mp3\",\"indexPos\":0,\"messageType\":\"song\"}";
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
String path = jsonObject.getString("pathInfo");
```

I haven't used Gson but try this and let me know if it works

Comment: Thank u for helping but I'm trying to use Gson to parse this JSON string into a whole object. Your way isnt using Gson and is getting only one key from the JSON.

Comment: You can get the others separately and then assigning them to the Model class

Comment: That is what ill do if I wont figure this out but since Gson library is suppose to do it for us, that is - map the values to the object fields then I would like to use that

Comment: Hove you found a solution yet ?

Comment: I have, it was my stupidity - passed a key from the JSON into the GSON library deserializer instead of the ENTIRE JSON.

Comment: You should consider adding your own answer then it may benefit others ;)